# Can someone help me find what my frame model is?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

A little backstory: so I bought the bike before 2 mounts and on the frame it says that its **Orange 224 evolution** but I browsed true the internet and it doesn't seem to be it the frames don't mach so I was stuck when I was trying to buy parts for the bike and that is why I'm asking for help if someone can identify the model of the bike.

This is **My Frame**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

This is the **Orange 224 evo**:
https://www.google.com/search?q=Orange+224+evo

[image]
 from https://archive.orangebikes.co.uk/bike/2009/224-evo_race/

Comment: bit more similar to the orange Five. but it's 20 years old or more so the current photos on image search might not show this bike. Try emailing Orange.

Comment: well i have alot of troble contacting them that is why i came here to ask for help

Comment: you know, it might be what it says it is, but the shock has been replaced with a shorter air shock and that adapter made to take up the space of the big spring

Comment: never noticed that but i still think if i put a bigger shock wont it make the rear gap too small?

Comment: also yes i know about the shock replacement ( im was not sure bcuse it didnt mach the  front triangle on the other's 224 evo's)

Comment: It's also very similar to the Orange Patriot (and similar), 2000-2006. A bigger/longer shock would require a different adaptor inside the frame and would result in more travel. The aim would be to keep the "gap at the back" the same or similar to how it is now

Comment: I think it's one of the older orange DH bikes built in the 2000s. I don't think you have a fake or whatever.

Comment: It's probably the bike in the line up that the Evo 224 replaced.

Comment: i think that is too but the original owner told me its 2008 frame he hasent told me a specific name so i was left to chose between if it is Patriot Or a 224 evo.

Comment: also has the stikers of a 224 evolution in the back

Comment: People change the stickers, it might not be the original paint. Difficult to find a 2008 catalogue, hey.

Comment: ye it is and thanks you have helped me alot now i finaly contacted orange bikes so ill see what will happen

Comment: Do you know who "Ricky Stevens" is/was ? That looks like a rider name lettered onto the frame.  Maybe a competitive cyclist back when this bike was newer ?

Comment: i dont know who that is but that is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The welding of the top tube to the head tube is definitely different.  The 2009 model you've linked to has a beefy gusset, whereas your bike does not.

However there are many similarities in the general design, so it looks like a bike made by Orange.  Whether its the exact Evolution 224 model you think it is, that's unknown as is the year.

Remember decals can be bought and applied by anyone, as can paint.

Your best option is to look through all the old catalogues looking for identifying parts that don't change, like the raised chainstay/swingarm and the welding on the frame.  Ignore forks, stem, saddle, grips, rotors, wheels, tyres, paint, stickers/transfers, cranks and anything else that can be changed.

**Links**

https://www.retrobike.co.uk/gallery2/v/Manufacturer+Archive/Orange+Archive/Orange+Catalogues/  has catalogues from 1990 to 1999

https://orangebikes.photoshelter.com/gallery/Brochures/G0000kNUdXp13dLI/

https://archive.orangebikes.co.uk/ covers 2009-2014

https://www.orangebikes.com/bike-archive/ shows 2015-2021.

Good luck with your search !

Comment: thanks alot for your help but i have allredy contacted Orange Bikes and i have found that my frame is Orange Patriot 66 around 2006.

Comment: @Juiciest It is perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Comment: @juciest Concur with Eric- do post that as a new answer, and accept that.  It is a far better answer than this one.